# why pssh command not working when sudo user?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sudo, pssh

Below is one of the part of my script, but I am struggling to get the solution.
I am using pssh command along with awk to filter particular column from user input OS command.
awk with pssh command only having an issue when sudo to any user.

Below Provide me correct input.

```
pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i 'echo $(echo ), $(uptime|awk '\''{print $3}'\'')'
[1] 13:15:40 [SUCCESS] Host1
, 75
[2] 13:15:40 [SUCCESS] Host2
, 59
[3] 13:15:40 [SUCCESS] Host3
, 147
```

But below provide me incorrect input (gives output of uname -a) when sudo to quser.

```
sudo -i -u quser pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i 'echo $(echo ), $(uptime|awk '\''{print $3}'\'')'
[1] 13:16:11 [SUCCESS] host1
, 13:16pm up 147 days 4:48, 1 user, load average: 0.02, 0.05, 0.01
[2] 13:16:11 [SUCCESS] host2
, 13:16pm up 59 days 3:04, 0 users, load average: 0.52, 0.29, 0.22
[3] 13:16:11 [SUCCESS] host3
, 13:16pm up 75 days 3:38, 0 users, load average: 0.03, 0.02, 0.00
```

Comment: What is `echo $(echo ),` supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your quoting is incomplete i.e. your `$3` is getting lost somewhere and you get this:

```
 $ echo $(echo ), $(uptime|awk '{print}')
 , 16:54:39 up 7 days, 1:36, 14 users, load average: 0.30, 0.27, 0.27
```

In such cases I always suggest to enable shell debugging, i.e.

```
$ set -x; echo $(echo ), $(uptime|awk '{print}')
++ echo
++ uptime
++ awk '{print}'
+ echo , 16:56:14 up 7 days, 1:37, 14 users, load average: 0.16, 0.25, 0.26
, 16:56:14 up 7 days, 1:37, 14 users, load average: 0.16, 0.25, 0.26
```

I think all what you are missing is to quote the `$` too, ie.

```bash
$ pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i 'echo $(echo ), $(uptime|awk '\''{print \$3}'\'')'
```

To get the quoting correct you might have to play with the numbers of `\`.